# How can i add custom domain e.g. selenium.test.com to gitlab web container using a gitlab-ci.yml so that selenium service can connect to it

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gitlab, pipeline

I'm configuring automated tests for a GitLab pipeline. Here's a glimpse of what my .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like

```
image: php:8.1-apache

services:
  - name: axllent/mailpit
    alias: selenium-mailpit
  - name: mariadb:10.4
    alias: mysql
  - name: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    alias: selenium-chrome

variables:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
  MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
  MYSQL_DATABASE: test_database
  MYSQL_USER: test_user
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: test_user
  MYSQL_HOST: mysql
  FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true"

before_script:
.....


selenium_tests:
  script:
    ....
    - php vendor/bin/codecept run
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/CodeCeptionTests/tests/_output
    # make the report available in Gitlab UI. see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/unit_test_reports.html
    reports:
      junit: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/CodeCeptionTests/tests/_output/report.xml
```

because i'm using FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true" the web container is accessible under "build." However, I also need it to be accessible under a custom domain, such as "selenium.test.com"

The issue lies in the fact that the selenium/standalone-chrome service cannot resolve the new name. I've attempted adding it to hosts and using runners, but I haven't been able to find a viable solution.

I'm using Codeception for testing, and due to external services, I need the testing domain to match the live domain, or at the very least, have a different subdomain.

I've attempted various approaches, including adding hosts to the main container, installing Selenium directly on the container, and utilizing runners, but none of these methods have worked.